# PIG Latin No error:Output is blank while executing FOREACH..GENERATE statement

Tags: apache-pig

Getting incorrect output while executing FOREACH statement.

step 1) Copied a csv file from S3 to hdfs without header

step 2) In hdfs mode, i tried to load the same file in an alias in pig.(Dump is working fine till this)

```
grunt> rec = Load '/home/Output/' using PigStorage(',') AS (Student:chararray,School:chararray,Year:int,Awards:int);
grunt> dump rec
```

;
step 3) Then i grouped it and tried to count the number of awards.

```
grunt>rec2 = FOREACH rec1 GENERATE group as Country,SUM(rec.Awards) as Award_count;
```

When i m dumping rec2, there is no error but output is (,)

The above command is working perfectly when using in local mode.I am getting desired output.

Comment: how did generate rec1 can u post?

Comment: There is no country field in your load statement but you have group as country in Step4,what did you group your records on?

Comment: Silly me...i got my mistake...While loading i used PigStorage(',')  which should not be required as i am loading from hdfs and the record is tab separated. Now it worked.       and @TKHN ...Sorry for the command.. i meant to write as  rec2 = FOREACH (GROUP rec BY School) GENERATE group as School,SUM(rec.Awards) as Award_count; ....Now it worked..thanks..

Comment: @inquisitive_mind ..Sorry for the command.. i meant to write as rec2 = FOREACH (GROUP rec BY School) GENERATE group as School,SUM(rec.Awards) as Award_count; ....Now it worked..thanks..